# WebLogic / SOA suite install - Oracle HOME confusion

Tags: weblogic, soa, oracle11g, weblogic-10.x, middleware

I am reading Oracle SOA Suite 11gR1 and try to follow the tutorial:
http://www.packtpub.com/article/installation-configuration-oracle-soa-suite-11g-1

This is all on a Win 7 machine btw.

When I create the domain (Middle of page) and try to associate the EnterPrise Manager with the Oracle_SOA1 home I do not have that option. For some reason its says next Oracle_Common next to it and I am not experienced enough to understand why.

Can someone please let me know how to fix that and what I missed. Maybe I need to uninstall everything and start over.

I installed Oracle DB 11gR2, WebLogic 10.3 and SOA suite 11gR1 and Jdev.

I am able to start the servers and browse to http://localhost:7001/console BUT I can NOT browse to http://localhost:7001/em. I assume it has something to do with the problem mentioned above.

I am including a screen shot of my domain creation window:
[image]
I hope someone can please help me with this, I would like to continue with the book to learn SOA.

Thank you,

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Enterprise Manager is a common component.  It is not associated with Oracle_SOA as you are understanding it.  Oracle_common is effectively where it lives.

You need to select the checkbox when creating your domain for the Enterprise Manager if you want to use it.

You can also select Oracle SOA_Suite if you also wish that to be in your domain.

The bracketed items on the right of each of the selections are advising you of the code block that they belong to, not whether they are associated with SOA, etc.

You can install multiple types into a single domain if you want, although things like SOA Suite you can only have one of the choices.

If you wish to have it in your existing domain run the config for domain creation again and this time extend an existing domain.  Then you can add additional functionality to that domain by selecting additional checkboxes.

Comment: SingleDomain is only since 11gR4

Comment: Single domain is actually since 11gR3

Answer (score 0):

Oracle EM is required for use with SOA Suite. The EM Fusion Middleware Control Panel is what you use to reply, monitor, test and manage composites.